# Pass in a typedef struct to a function that expects the original struct

Tags: c, struct

In C, `typedef` is used to create an additional name (alias) for another data type, but does not create a new type, except in the obscure case of a qualified typedef of an array type where the typedef qualifiers are transferred to the array element type.

If we have a function that takes in a struct, is it possible to pass in the typedef'd type?

For example, suppose we have:

```
typedef struct foo {
  ...
} Bar;

void func1(struct foo* arg0) {
  // do something
}
```

Is it possible to do:

```
Bar bar0;
func1(bar0);
```

If so, why is it possible? The function header specifies that it takes in an argument of type `struct foo*`, not `*Bar`

Comment: That shouldn't be possible. The function takes a pointer, but you're passing a structure.

Comment: It would work if you wrote `func1(&bar0)`.

Comment: You said it yourself, `typedef` doesn't introduce a new type. Why wouldn't it work? (apart from missing `&`)

Comment: "Is it possible to do ...." Did you try it? What was the result?

Answer (score 2):

`struct foo` is compatible with `Bar` so one can be used in place of the other, no problem.

This `func1(bar0);` is however passing a struct by value, so you get a compiler error.